# How AWS Cloudfront forward my request Initiated by S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

This may be a simple question, but I can't find any tutorials for it

My website all store in S3 bucket, but the front-end and back-end are stores in different buckets

In my front-end website, JS initiated a request URL use relative path, like `/api/***`, the request URL to be `http://front-end.com/api/***`.
how can I make all these requests redirect to my back-end bucket. like this:
`http://back-end.com/api/***`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/redirect-website-requests.html

this doc can't seem to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to use different domain names to serves your content ?
To redirect from http://front-end.com/api/*** to http://back-end.com/api/***, there are couple of ways:
1. Use Lambda@edge viewer request function to redirect with 301/302 with new URL. 
2. Use S3 bucket for redirection.
In any of above case, you need both front-end.com and back-end.com to point to CloudFront so that you can serve them from CloudFront.

An easy way is to access all of them using  front-end.com and create a cache behavior which Path pattern "/api/*" and choose the Origin bucket where you want to make the request.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have made both buckets relative to CloudFront, but for the second way, If I choose “Redirect request” option, I can't choose "Use this bucket to host", I don't know is work? My website can still find my index.html by default?